# Loaded an object using OBJLoader; how to compute the position of something in it? (three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am rendering a 3D human head using three.js and [OBJLoader](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj):

```js
let renderer, camera, scene, head, light, projectiles;

new THREE.OBJLoader().load(objUrl, initialize);

function initialize(obj) {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  head = obj.clone();
  head.children.forEach(child => child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "#ffc700" }));
  head.position.y = -34;
  head.position.z = -110;
  scene.add(head);
  
  light = new THREE.SpotLight();
  light.target = head;
  scene.add(light);
  
  projectiles = [];

  window.addEventListener("mousedown", createProjectile, false);

  animate();
}

function animate() {
  head.rotation.y += THREE.Math.degToRad(1);

  projectiles.forEach(updateProjectile);

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function createProjectile() {
  let projectile = new THREE.Mesh();
  projectile.material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: "#ff0000" });
  projectile.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 20, 20);
  projectile.position.copy(getMouthPosition());
  scene.add(projectile);
  projectiles.push(projectile);
}

function updateProjectile(projectile) {
  // TODO: Move projectile in the direction the mouth was facing when projectile was first created.
  projectile.position.x += 2;
}

function getMouthPosition() {
  // TODO: Determine the world position of the mouth.
  let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(head);
  return box.getCenter();
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.js">
</script>

<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/three-obj-loader@1.1.3">
</script>

<script>
  threeObjLoader(THREE);
  objUrl = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/f32fc45/examples/obj/walt/WaltHead.obj";
</script>
```

When the mouse is clicked, I want to "shoot" a projectile/bullet from the rotating head's mouth. But as you can see from the `TODO` comments in the code, there are two functions I don't know how to implement: `getMouthPosition()` and `updateProjectile()`.

For `getMouthPosition()`, I want to determine the current position of the mouth and spawn the projectile at this location (ideally, just in front of the mouth).

For `updateProjectile()`, I want to move the projectile in the direction the head was facing at the time when the projectile was first created, like this:

[image: example]

If someone could shed light on how to write these functions, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: The head (`THREE.Group()`) has just one child element (`THREE.Mesh()`), so there's no information about where its mouth locates. You can find that point empyrically.

Comment: @prisoner849 Could you elaborate on how to do it empirically? If the head didn't have any rotation, I'd just compute the head's bounding box and then approximate the mouth position from that. But given that the head is rotating, I don't know how.

Comment: There's a very useful method `.localToWorld( v )` of `THREE.Object3D()`

Comment: Ummm, there is no way to do this. This is literally as if you asked **how to write a function `doMyProject()`**. Make a red cube, put it somewhere, see where it's at. Move it, see where it's at. Move it again see where it's at. Find mouth.

Comment: @pailhead That's how I found it )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look. Somehow you'll get where the mouth locates (in coordinates of the `head` group it locates at about `[0, 25, 20]`). Then, to get position of the mouth of the spinning head, you can use `.localToWorld(v)` method, like so:

```
head.localToWorld(mouthPosition.copy(spawnPoint.position));
```

`spawnPoint` is a "helper" object to indicate where our spawn point is.

Further, you have to know where your head points at. You can get it with another method `.getWorldDirection()` of the `head` object.

Concluding all of this: you know position of the head's mouth, you know its direction, thus you can cast a projectile, using those values.

```js
let renderer, camera, scene, head, light, projectiles, spawnPoint, clock = new THREE.Clock(), delta = 0;

new THREE.OBJLoader().load(objUrl, initialize);

function initialize(obj) {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  head = obj.clone();
  head.children.forEach(child => child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff }));
  head.position.y = -34;
  head.position.z = -110;
  scene.add(head);
  
  light = new THREE.SpotLight();
  light.target = head;
  scene.add(light);
  
  spawnPoint = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "red", wireframe: true}));
  spawnPoint.position.set(0, 25, 20);
  head.add(spawnPoint);
  
  projectiles = [];

  window.addEventListener("mousedown", event => { createProjectile(); }, false);
  
  animate();
}

function animate() {
  delta = clock.getDelta();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
  head.rotation.y += THREE.Math.degToRad(20) * delta;

  projectiles.forEach(p => {
    p.position.addScaledVector(p.userData.direction, p.userData.speed * delta);
  });

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function createProjectile() {
  let projectile = new THREE.Mesh();
  projectile.material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
  projectile.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 16, 12);
  let pos = getMouthPosition();
  console.log("pos", pos);
  projectile.position.copy(pos);
  projectile.userData.direction = new THREE.Vector3().copy(head.getWorldDirection().normalize());
  console.log(projectile.userData.direction);
  projectile.userData.speed = 50;
  scene.add(projectile);
  projectiles.push(projectile);
  console.log(projectiles);
}

function getMouthPosition() {
  let mouthPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
  console.log("spawnPoint", spawnPoint);
  head.localToWorld(mouthPosition.copy(spawnPoint.position));
  console.log("mouthPosition", mouthPosition);
  return mouthPosition;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.js">
</script>

<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/three-obj-loader@1.1.3">
</script>

<script>
  threeObjLoader(THREE);
  objUrl = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/f32fc45/examples/obj/walt/WaltHead.obj";
</script>
```